How to import a custom Python module programatically in Snowpark (Snowflake Python Worksheet)
I have a git repo hosting on a stage and would like to access a module from my repo programmatically in Snowpark, rather than through the UI package manager.
Ideally, assuming I have file on a stage
@my_github_stage/my_module.py
I'd like to somehow import it
# The Snowpark package is required for Python Worksheets. 
# You can add more packages by selecting them using the Packages control and then importing them.

import snowflake.snowpark as snowpark

#### Would need something like this to import from a stage
import @my_github_stage.my_module 

def main(session: snowpark.Session): 
    
    print(my_module.MY_CONSTANT)
    return my_module.MY_CONSTANT

Tried to access the Snowpark documentation, but cannot find anything specific. Thanks for any help!
